# Circular buffer optimizations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, circular-buffer

I've got a circular buffer that has size power of 2. My goal is to optimize its work. Here's brief code:

```
class CircularBuffer
{
public:
  CircularBuffer(unsigned int bufferSize); // align this size to power of 2
  void read(char * dst, unsigned int bytes);
  void write(char * src, unsigned int bytes);
private:
  unsigned int m_readOffset;
  unsigned int m_writeOffset;
  std::vector<char> m_buffer;
};

CircularBuffer::write(char * src, unsigned int bytes)
{
  int dif = bytes - (m_buffer.size() - m_writeOffset);
  unsigned int mask = ~(dif >> 31); // 0 or 0xFFFFFFFF
  dif &= mask; // now i know how much bytes i need to put at the beginning of the buffer
  memcpy(&m_buffer[m_writeOffset], src, bytes - dif);
  memcpy(&m_buffer[0], src + bytes - dif, dif);
  m_writeOffset = (m_wirteffset + bytes) & (m_buffer.size() -1);
}
```

`m_writeOffset` indicates how many bytes already put in buffer.
As you can see I get rid of conditions like if (remain size in buff < srcSize) etc, and calculate writeOffset using bitmask.

But my lead programmer tells me there's a way to calculate how many bytes to put at the end of the buffer and how many bytes to put at the start using bitwise operations, because size of buffer is power of 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who told you there was a way?

Comment: Be aware that low-level tricks != efficient code. Try the standard library circular buffer ([`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)) and profile it.

Comment: Low-level tricks = hard to read and full of bugs. It seems your lead programmer is "clever" but not clever. "Clever" programmers only cause trouble. You see, if you tried to get your ::write method through a code review with me, I'd ask you to look up in the C++ standard what the result of right-shifting a negative integer is and where exactly it says that the sign is duplicated. And then you would be stuck because you won't find this information, because it's not there. Right-shifting a negative integer is implementation defined and not portable.

Comment: gnasher729, so what do you think should i do? If you hard to read this maybe you hard to understand what is happening there? If this function is used in multi-threaded highly executable block of code, we really see the difference in performance between "good readable" code and "good implemented" code. I completely agree about right-shifting implementation, so we can trust compilier documentation. Is there anybody who would just try to find technical decision instead of give advices how to programm?

Comment: Manu343726, std::deque is container of objects, it is not memory fifo. As you see i use std::vector as smart pointer of heap memory. That's all. How do you suppose to utilise std::deque? insert - remove operations that realloc memory on each call? i don't see efficient code here.

Comment: Irregardless of the suitability of the example code for code review or other scrutiny, providing a helpful answer would be more effective than bashing the example code or suggesting diversionary courses of action.

Answer (score -1):

You are already using unsigned variables to keep track of the front and back of your queue (this is good); simply increment `m_writeOffset` on each write (enqueue) operation and increment `m_readOffset` on each read (dequeue) operation. Calculating the remaining amount of buffer elements is as simple as:

```
// returns the distance between m_readOffset and m_writeOffset
// (the count of the actual buffer elements):
uint32_t CircularBuffer::Size()
{
    if (m_readOffset < m_writeOffset)
    {
        return (m_writeOffset - m_readOffset);
    }
    else
    {
        return (m_readOffset - m_writeOffset);
    }
}
```

Check out the source code to my STL template implementation of a base-2 circular queue:

[CircularQueue.h](https://github.com/UniversalProgrammingOrganization/upo-lib/blob/master/upo-lib/CircularQueue.h)

[CircularQueue.cpp](https://github.com/UniversalProgrammingOrganization/upo-lib/blob/master/upo-lib/CircularQueue.cpp)

Comment: It is wrong. Here is an example: m_ReadOffset = 4, m_WriteOffset = 2. By your logic, the count of actual buffer elements will be always 4-2=2 with regardless of actual Capacity. Since m_WriteOffset less than m_ReadOffset, it means you already filled elements after m_ReadOffset till the end of the array plus elements starting from the 0 index of array till m_WriteOffset.